# Android minifyEnabled = true proguard deleting duplicated string resource on library projects?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have my app divided into library modules, and i have two modules that define the same string resource in their build.gradle files. Let's say module A and module B and module A depends on module B.

Module A
The string is buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", ""https://MY.URL.com/""

Module B
The string is buildConfigField "String", "BASE_URL", ""https://MY.URL.com/""

When i run module A with its test app and having **minifyEnabled false**, everything works fine but if i run this with **minifyEnabled true** then **Module A** shows the **BASE_URL** string resource but **Module B** **BASE_URL** resource is **null**

Any ideas of what i have to do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do the modules have different packages defined in their `AndroidManifest.xml`? `BuildConfig` is generated with manifest package – perhaps there's a collision?

Comment: @AlexKrupa yes, for example Module A package is **com.app.modulea** and Module B is **com.app.moduleb**